# Category Equivalence between Curves and Fields of Transcendence degree $1$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves

It is a well known fact that there exist a so called threefold category equivalence between following tree categories:

1) the category of finitely generated field extensions $K/k$ of transcendence degree 1

2) category of normal integral curves (over $k$) and dominant rational maps

3) compact Riemann surfaces and holomorphic maps

By taking the generic fiber (resp the field of meromorphic functions) it's quite easy to obtain a functor from 2) and 3) to 1).

Could anybody sketch the construction of the functors from 1) to 2) and from 1) to 3)?

My considerations:

for 1) to 2):

here I have two problems namely

i) how to define the functor $K \to X_K$

ii) and if we have a finite morphism (=inclusion) of fields  $\phi: K \subset L$ of transcendence degree $1$  and assume I know how to construct $X_K$ and $X_L$ in i) then there exist open sets $U \subset X_K, V \subset X_L$ to which $\phi$ the field map $\phi$ can be extended: $f_{\phi}: V \to U$. We obtain a ***rational*** morphism $X_L \dashrightarrow X_K$.

How can this dashed arrow be extended to a well defined map $X_L \to X_K$?

Regarding 1) to 2): no idea

remark: a curve is here defined as a 1-dimensional proper k-scheme

Comment: This is covered in detail in chapter 1 section 6 of Hartshorne's _Algebraic Geometry_.

Comment: @KReiser Let $K/k(t)$ a finite extension and $R =k[x_1,\ldots,x_n]/I$ the integral closure of $k[t]$. $V(I)$ is a smooth affine curve (and its function field is $K$) but its projective closure doesn't need to be smooth. Is there a common way to repair its few singular points above $t=\infty$ ? I think taking iteratively a singular point $p$, the $x_j$ with highest pole at $p$, an uniformizer $\pi$ chosen such that all the other poles of $x_{n+1}=\pi x_j$ are simple, then add $x_{n+1}$ to the generating set of $R$, this should work to obtain an affine curve whose projective closure is smooth.

Comment: @reuns that's not the usual method of proof (you want to consider valuation rings of $K/k$ rather than exhibiting $K$ as a finite extension of $k(t)$), but you can fix it with normalization, which is an answer to every problem involving curves with singularities.

Comment: @reuns: Why $V(I)$ is smooth? How to see it? This is equivalent to show that $R =k[x_1,\ldots,x_n]/I$ localized at every prime $p \subset R$ is regular. Since $R$ is integral over $k[t]$ so $\dim(R)=1$ and it suffice to show that the max ideal $m_p$ of local ring $R_p$ is principal or (by Nakayama) equivalently $m_p/m_p^2$ is one dimensional vector space. But I can't find the argument

Comment: @reuns: UPDATE concerning my remark from few days ago: 
my problem is to deduce that your $R$ (= integral closure of $k[t]$ in $K$ is locally regular. My previous attempts to show that directly as explained in comments above failed but nevertheless accourding to https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/00PD it suffice to show that the $R_p$'s are normal, i.e. $R_p$ is the integral closure of $Frac(R)$ for every prime $p$. Do you see an argument? I don't know if it is possible to deduce that from that fact that $R$ is integral closure of $k[t]$ in $K$.

Comment: $R_p$ is integrally closed. You may start from the set of discrete valuations of $K$, the approximation theorem is that for any finite set of valuations $v_1,\ldots,v_j$ and any $e_i$ there is some $f \in K$ such that $v_i(f) 
= e_i$. Then $O_{v_i} = \{ a \in K, v_i(a) \ge 0\}$, look at $\bigcap_{i=1}^j O_{v_i} $, which subrings are of finite index (and keep the same fraction field), which ones are integrally closed, how many prime and maximal ideals do they have, which ones are PID ? Those things are detailed in "Algebraic function fields and codes"

Comment: @reuns: yes that's true. The $O_{v_i}$ are by definition DVR's (since induced by discrete valuations), and therefore integrally closed again by https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/00PD. But how do they relate to the localizations $R_p$ of $R= k[x_1,\ldots,x_n]/I$ from your first comment? Are ***all*** $P_p$ of the shape $O_{v}$? Why?