# Smooth Affine Curve arises from a Field Extension

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves

My question arises from following former thread of mine:[Category Equivalence between Curves and Fields of Transcendence degree $1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3231233/category-equivalence-between-curves-and-fields-of-transcendence-degree-1)

and refers to a comment of @reuns:

> Let $K/k(t)$ a finite extension and $R=k[x_1,…,x_n]/I$ the integral closure of $k[t]$. $V(I)$ is a smooth affine curve (and its function field is $K$) but its projective closure doesn't need to be smooth...

My question is how to see that the resulting scheme $V(I) = Spec(k[x_1,…,x_n]/I$ is a ***smooth*** curve?

My considerations:

By definition of smoothness this is equivalent to show that $R=k[x_1,…,x_n]/I $localized at every prime $p⊂R$ is regular. Since $R$ is integral over $k[t]$ so $dim(R)=1$ and it suffice to show that the max ideal mp of local ring $R_p $ is principal or (by Nakayama) equivalently $m_p/m^2_p$ is one dimensional vector space. But from here I'm stuck in finding an argument.

Comment: it's a fact that for dimension 1 Noetherian local rings,  regular is same as normal (and same as DVR etc). But the normal to regular proof seems to me to be a slightly involved. See https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/00PD and https://math.stanford.edu/~vakil/0708-216/216class22.pdf

Comment: @usr0192: One point I still not understand: According to the linked sources it suffice to show that locally $R$ is normal (so $R$ is algebraic closure of $Frac(R)$). This would then imply that $V(I)$ is normal and equivalently regular.

By definition $R$ is the algebraic closure of $k[t]$ in $K$. But why is then $R$ algebraically closed (=normal)? If we take a $f \in Frac(R)$ which fullfils a polynomial equation $P(f)= \sum_k a_k f^k$ with $a_j \in R$ why $f \in R$?

Comment: you are basically asking why the integral closure is integrally closed. I googled and found the following link which may or may not be helpful. If it's not, any commutative algebra or algebraic number theory text section on integral closure would help. The main thing is integral extensions are closely related to module-finite extensions and this is a bit easier to work with than the equation that the definition of integral gives https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Integral_Closure_is_Integrally_Closed